# How to make Android Java code call Node.js code?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, firebase-notifications

I have some code that I have and I want to invoke some Node.js code and I'm not sure how to go about this. I want to implement these `Firebase` notifications as described in this blog post:

> https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

But there is some Node.js code that will listen on my Firebase Database and will detect if there is something being inserted into my database. Is there any way I can "deploy" this code somewhere on my `Android` application and have it so that this code will be invoked? Below is the Node.js code I woudl want to get invoked from my `Android` application:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var request = require('request');

var API_KEY = "..."; // Your Firebase Cloud Server API key

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: ".json",
  databaseURL: "https://.firebaseio.com/"
});
ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
  var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
  ref.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
    var request = requestSnapshot.val();
    sendNotificationToUser(
      request.username, 
      request.message,
      function() {
        request.ref().remove();
      }
    );
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
};

function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      notification: {
        title: message
      },
      to : '/topics/user_'+username
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
    }
    else {
      onSuccess();
    }
  });
}

// start listening
listenForNotificationRequests();
```

I would imagine I would need to host the code somewhere, but I feel like if all I need is to host one file somewhere it wouldn't be necessarily to deploy something like Google App Engine or Heroku unless I am mistaken. I guess I am just confused on how I can communicate between this file and the Java Android code I've written so far. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can install something like Termux on the android and install node.js on it, and host your code locally on the device, but I must say that it seems like a strange way to use a node.js server (but it sure does sound fun!)

Take a look at this guide for installing Termux and node.js on your Android:
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-node-js-application-on-android-part-1-termux-vim-and-node-js-dfa90c28958f#.z9zjw5o8w

I am not sure how well the network traffic will flow from your node.js server to the database and back considering it is being hosted from inside a sort of emulator on the Android, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look at this! The thing is I would want to host this on a cloud platform just so I don't have to worry so much about the network traffic and having to host the server and ensuring scalability. Would you have any other solutions? This is cool though I'll look at it

Comment: Sorry, you say you would like to host it on the cloud platform or you wouldn't?

Comment: I would like to because I feel like it take out all the hassle out of maintaining it myself. Are there any free solutions f to do this?

Comment: Many cloud platforms have free trials (like Google Cloud's 30-60 day with a $300 credit to 'spend') and you can check the following link for some more resources for free hosting of node.js code (http://www.hostingadvice.com/blog/where-to-find-free-node-js-hosting/) but this brings up the question "What are  you hosting?" Because if you run your node.js code inside your Android app then there is nothing to host. I would just write your node.js code locally, then deploy it to something like google compute (I do this on a 'micro' VM for $4 a month). Is this the sort of thing you are thinking?

Comment: Yes! When you mention that you can run your nose.js code inside your Android app, how would I do that? I am confused on that part. The other thing is could you elaborate on how I can host this 'micro VM' ? I am not too familiar with Google compute

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to say that the nodejs was hosted 'inside the app', I meant 'on the Android device' using Termux. This means you must install Termux + your server on each device next to the app, so this might end up being a "1-user app". As for the micro VM, this is just a Virtual Machine instance on G-Compute. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance It's actually MUCH easier than you might think. You just make an account, create an instance (see instructions in link) and it's like you have a computer in the cloud! You remote in and manage it with SSH.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ryan. I really appreciate the effort. I will look into Frank's answer then in that case.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can "deploy" this code somewhere on my Android application and have it so that this code will be invoked?

No. You don't run node.js code inside you Android application. That would defeat the purpose of separating the code.

The Node.js code runs on a so-called app server. Such an app server is a trusted place where you can run code. Since you control such a server (after all, nobody else has access to it), you can trust that the code that runs on the server is the code that you put there.

On your users' Android device, you can run code. But you can never trust that the code running on the device is the code that you sent there. After all the user can make changes to the app.

You should never mix application code with code that runs on a trusted server. The Node.js script from my article requires the Firebase Cloud Messaging server key to be able to send messages to devices. Since having access to this key allows you to send messages on your project's behalf, it should only be present on trusted serves - such as your app server.

Comment: I see. Thanks for this. Any examples of what I can use as a a free app server I can test this out putting the Node.js code with?

Comment: Recommending such services is off-topic for Stack Overflow. But I expect that a search for "free app server that can run node" will give some good results.

Comment: @user1871869 This is a better answer than mine. Just use node.js for what it was intended for, and keep it off the Android.

Comment: ah of course haha sorry. I don't know how I missed that. Too busy looking for things I can answer I guess lol.